# php PDO transfer resultset to database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, bulkinsert

I try to transfer a huge amount of data (around 200k records every few minutes) from one to another database (also on two different servers). The tableschema on both tables is both dbs is the same.

So whats the best way to transfer a huge resultset into a db without causing an memory limit error.

my current solution looks like this. But this means I run about 200k Insert querys in `writeToDB2()` and that seems to be not very effective to me.

```
$stmt = $this->db_1->query("SELECT foo from bar");
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    writeToDB2($row);
}
```

Does anyone knew a better solution to bulk transfer the data?

Comment: Replication? Although has its own drawback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer works only if the same user has access to both databases.

A general purpose solution is to forget about PHP and PDO at all and use console mysql shell and mysqldump like

```
mysqldump -uuser1 -ppassword1 db1 tablename | mysql -uuser2 -ppassword2 db2
```

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately mysql supports INSERT SELECT spanning databases.

```
$stmt = $this->db_1->query("INSERT INTO db2.bar(foo) SELECT foo from db1.bar");
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Would be a neat solution but unfortunately those thow databases dont run on the same server. So I have two db-handels

Comment: then your only option is replication.